# Python search string with similar name in oratab file

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I have written script in python in which this script will take name from user and search in a file after getting result it will be splited and will export to OS environment variable.

The problem is that while searching name in a file their are two name say GOCO and GOCO01 and if user enter GOCO but result output or export output is GOCO01 because it is coming first in file ocurrance i want if user select GOCO then GOCO is to be exported

My script:-

```
name_db = input("Please enter a Database Name: ")
with open("/etc/oratab") as f:
    for line in f:
     if name_db in line:
      var1= line
   os.environ['ORACLE_SID']=var1.split(':')[0]
   os.environ['ORACLE_HOME']=var1.split(':')[1]
```

print(name_db)

GOCO

print (os.environ['ORACLE_SID'])

GOCO01

ORATAB File Content:-

```
ATING001:/home/oracle/dbhome_1:Y
GOCO01:/home/oracle/dbhome_1:Y
GOCO:/home/oracle/dbhome_1:Y
SYM1:/home/oracle/dbhome_1:Y
SYM2:/home/oracle/dbhome_1:Y
```

I want output to be

print (os.environ['ORACLE_SID'])

GOCO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a case for fuzzy matching?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import difflib
import os

name_db = input('Please enter a Database Name: ')
fuzzy_match = lambda line: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, name_db.lower(), line.lower()).ratio()
best_line = max([line.strip() for line in open('/etc/oratab')], key=fuzzy_match)
os.environ['ORACLE_SID']=best_line.split(':')[0]
os.environ['ORACLE_HOME']=best_line.split(':')[1]
```

Note the `lower()` calls, so this implementation is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to search for the name entered by the user, concatenated with a `:`. Like this:

```
term_to_search = name_db + ':'
if term_to_search in line:
    var1 = line
```

Comment: now only take into account that comments are allowed in the /etc/oratab file .... (A line starting with the ORACLE_SID followed by ORACLE_HOME with a ":" delimited is what we are looking for.  ORACLE_SID:ORACLE_HOME: